# assign 0 or 1 based on conditional probability + previous result in R

Tags: r

I'm doing a simulation study and I have some problem generating data that meet certain conditions.

My first simulated data looks like below.

```
       A1    A2    A3
  1    0     0     0 
  2    0     1     1
  3    0     0     1
  -
1151   1     1     1
```

As you can see N=1151, and the summary shows that

```
 A1 (0: 571, 1:580)
 A2 (0: 591, 1:560)
 A3 (0: 423, 1:728)
```

I have to generate data (for the second simulation) based on the following conditional probability

```
        0        1
 0    .87       .13
 1     .2        .8
```

For example, the second person, who had previous data looked like below,

```
       A1    A2    A3
  1    0     1     1
```

would have 87% of having '0' for A1, 20% of having '0' for A2 and 80% of having '1' for A3 for the second simulation, and I would like to generate date based on these probabilities.

I was wondering how I can write these in R code.

All I can think of is

```
 M=(A1=='1')
 rbinom(M,size=1,0.87)
```

I know this is not right. But, based on my limited R knowledge, I can't think of anything else. 
I appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I guess what you are simulating is kind of ***Markov chain*** If that is true, then below are two approaches to mimic the Markov process (personally I prefer the recursive one):

---

- ## Recursive approach

The conditional probability is applied over the previous value to get the current value, recursively

```
N <- 1151

# transition matrix
transProb <- matrix(c(0.87, 0.2, 0.13, 0.8), nrow = 2)

# recursive representation of Markov chain
f <- function(v, n) {
    if (n == 1) return(v)
    p <- f(v, n - 1)
    u <- tail(p,1)
    c(p, sample(c(0, 1), 1, prob = transProb[ifelse(u,2,1),]))
}

# initial value
x0 <- c(A1 = 0, A2 = 0, A3 = 0)
res <- as.data.frame(sapply(x0, f, N))
```

---

- ## Transition matrix approach

  You can compute your transition matrix first and then generate random value according to the initial value as well as the current conditional probability.

```
N <- 1151

# transition prob. matrix
transProb <- matrix(c(0.87, 0.2, 0.13, 0.8), nrow = 2)
# evolution of transition prob. matrix
transProbChain <- Reduce(`%*%`, c(list(diag(2)), replicate(N - 1, transProb, simplify = FALSE)), accumulate = TRUE)

# random variable generator
f <- Vectorize(function(x0, ntime) {
  sample(c(0, 1), 1, prob = transProbChain[[ntime]][ifelse(x0,2,1),])
}, vectorize.args = "ntime")

# initial values
x0 <- c(A1 = 0, A2 = 0, A3 = 0)
ntime <- seq(N)
# generate data frame as output
res <- as.data.frame(sapply(x0, f, ntime))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, a basic for-loop-based brute-force approach would be

```
ConDraw = function(x){ 
   ifelse(x == 1, 
          sample(c(0,1), 1, prob = c(0.2, 0.8)), 
          sample(c(0,1), 1, prob = c(0.87, 0.13)))
}

iter = 20
Init = 1
Result = vector(mode = "numeric", length = iter)

for (i in 1:iter) {
   Result[i] = ConDraw(Init)
   Init = Result[i]
}
```

with **output**

```
> Result
 [1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

As far as I see you'll do that separately once for `Init = 0` and twice for `Init = 1` and you should be good. There are more elegant ways to solve this, I'm sure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-line solution:

```r
apply(df, 2, function(x) rbinom(length(x), 1, c(0.13, 0.8)[x+1]))
```

This works because you can pass a vector of probabilities to `rbinom`. You can use the zeros and ones of the previous sample as indices of the two probabilities provided you add one to them first.

You only need the probabilities from the second column, since it is the complement of the first column.

Using `apply` allows you to do this column-wise for your matrix or dataframe.

To demonstrate, I'll generate a small test sample which shows the general principle:

```r
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(A1 = rbinom(9, 1, 0.5), A2 = rbinom(9, 1, 0.2), A3 = rbinom(9, 1, 0.7))
df
#>   A1 A2 A3
#> 1  0  0  1
#> 2  0  0  1
#> 3  1  1  1
#> 4  0  0  0
#> 5  0  0  1
#> 6  0  0  0
#> 7  1  0  1
#> 8  0  0  1
#> 9  1  0  0
```

So now...

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) rbinom(length(x), 1, c(0.13, 0.8)[x+1]))
#>       A1 A2 A3
#>  [1,]  1  0  1
#>  [2,]  0  0  1
#>  [3,]  1  0  0
#>  [4,]  0  0  0
#>  [5,]  1  0  1
#>  [6,]  0  0  0
#>  [7,]  0  0  1
#>  [8,]  0  0  1
#>  [9,]  0  0  0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much. If I were able to give more than one vote, I would have voted your answer as well.